# Copy Paste VBA loop

Tags: vba, excel

I have an issue when running my VBA macro that I've written to transpose a dataset.  The main goal is to take this dataset row by row, and transpose it so columns B:K are new rows.

Here is a sample of what I am trying to do:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUcKO.png

I've written the following VBA, but all it is doing is basically creating a "shadow row" in a new sheet, which isn't what I want.

```
Sub LoopPaste()

Dim i As Long
Dim firstRow As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sheet1 As Worksheet
Dim sheet2 As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set sheet1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set sheet2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")

'Find the last row with data
lastRow = sheet1.Range("A:A").Find("*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

'This is the beginning of the loop
For i = firstRow To lastRow

    'Copying Company
     sheet2.Range("A" & i) = sheet1.Range("A" & i).Value

    'Copying Employees
    sheet2.Range("B" & i) = sheet1.Range("B" & i).Value
    sheet2.Range("B" & 1 + i) = sheet1.Range("C" & i).Value
    sheet2.Range("B" & 2 + i) = sheet1.Range("D" & i).Value
    sheet2.Range("B" & 3 + i) = sheet1.Range("E" & i).Value

Next i

End Sub
```

How can I get the loop to create a new row for each employee?

Comment: You could use the `Offset()` method of `Range`. To transpose rows to columns and vice versa, something that's located at `Offset(i, j)` from the top left of your source range will need to go at `Offset(j, i)` from the top left of your destination range.

Comment: I would agree with @jsheeran It would be easiest to loop through the columns and offset to a new sheet using ThisWorkbook.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value =positionInLoop(i)

Comment: Cool Points earned if you store in an array first, and then dump to sheet! :D

Comment: @jsheeran i attempted using the Offset method, but I get a run time Error of 1004 (application or object defined error).  Not sure how to get around this error.  After the VBA does the work up until the error, there isn't a new row added either, which is what I would like.  Column B is also empty.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I got bored and came up with this for you. * Should * be pretty quick and painless, but might require knowing the ranges before hand.

```
Private Sub this()

    Dim a() As Variant

    a = Application.Transpose(Worksheets(1).Range("a1:p1").Value)

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1:p1").Value = vbNullString

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1:a55").Value2 = a

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the idea:

```
Sub test()
    Dim src As Range, c As Range, target As Range
    Dim curRow As Long
    Set src = Intersect(Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion, Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0))
    Set target = Sheet2.Range("a1")
    curRow = src.Cells(1, 1).Row
    For Each c In src.Cells
        If c <> "" Then
            target = c.Value
            If c.Column = 1 Then
                Set target = target.Offset(0, 1) 'next column
            Else
                Set target = target.Offset(1, 0) 'next row
            End If
        Else
            'back to col 1
            If target.Column <> 1 Then Set target = target.Offset(0, -target.Column + 1)
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```